How can I use the unlisted NuGet package Azure.CodeSigning.Sdk to sign PowerShell files?
We generate PowerShell scripts dynamically, as they are tailored for the intended customer. Customers, however, start to require these files to be signed.
Since they are generated on the fly, a CI based solution will not fit.
I am looking into how to do this by code as I intend to use Azure Function to sign these files, but I cannot figure out how to use the SDK as referenced in Use other signing integrations with Trusted Signing.
Edit 1: signtool.exe is Windows only and Jsign does not yet support Trusted signing. I guess I could use signtool.exe or Jsign, but they must be pre-installed, and I don't know how to do that for an Azure Function.
Edit 2: ES512 is a signature algorithm which accepts a SHA512 digest/hash.
Edit 3: I discovered that RS512 works, while my previous attempt with ES512 doesn't.
Updated code:
var endpoint = new Uri("https://weu.codesigning.azure.net/");
const string codeSigningAccountName = "...";
const string certificateProfileName = "...";

var client = new CertificateProfileClient(new InteractiveBrowserCredential(), endpoint);

await using var stream = File.OpenRead("...");
var digest = await SHA512.HashDataAsync(stream);

var signRequest = new SignRequest(SignatureAlgorithm.RS512, digest);
var signOperation = await client.StartSignAsync(codeSigningAccountName, certificateProfileName, signRequest); // Fails here, obviously

var response = await signOperation.WaitForCompletionAsync();

The response contains a signature and a signing certificate, both byte arrays.
How can I use those to sign the PowerShell in code, on a non-Windows device?

The SDK is supposed to be open source, but I cannot find neither source code or documentation.
Links:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Azure.CodeSigning.Sdk
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/trusted-signing/how-to-signing-integrations#use-other-signing-integrations-with-trusted-signing
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/trusted-signing/how-to-signing-integrations

My Trusted Signing Account is set up in Azure, roles are assigned, the identity validation has passed, and a public certificate profile is created.

Did you try debugging?

Not sure what you mean by "debugging". In the mean time I discovered that signing with SignatureAlgorithm.RS512 works, while SignatureAlgorithm.ES512 doesn't.

I think this is a duplicate but just to add a bit more context, you are indeed sending the incorrect digest algorithm var digest = await SHA512.HashDataAsync(stream); for Signing ES512. RS512 is the appropriate sign algorithm for the SHA512 hashed digest.
